# Is there a common class that has MySQL error numbers in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I just wrote this beautiful line of code.

```
if(sex.getErrorCode() == 1213) // deadlock
```

Terrible magic number.  Of course I could code up all of my own magic numbers, but shouldn't this exist somewhere already?

Not sure where to look - JDBC shouldn't really have MySQL specific information and I don't have any MySQL classes in my file or know of MySQL jars.

Comment: They're all documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html  and unless oracle goes nutjob on us, they're not likely to change.

Comment: why aren't you using the SQL state? if it's not specific enough, you CAN use the constants from com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlErrors class in the MySQL JDBC driver. That class is not part of any public API so it's possible it may change or be moved at some point down the line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL Connector/J's [`com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLErrorNumbers`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/connectorj/trunk/view/head:/src/com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlErrorNumbers.java) class defines a series of constants which you can compare `SQLException.getErrorCode()` against. E.g:

```
if(e.getErrorCode() == MysqlErrorNumbers.ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK) { }
```

This list is somewhat [documented in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-error-sqlstates.html).

Comment: Kudos, I haven't worked on this in a while but this looks to be what I couldn't find. Since you're new and solved an old problem I'll throw a bounty your way.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain and @cc me? I'd like to give this answer a bounty but if there's something wrong with it I'd like to know first.

Comment: Perhaps the link to an unofficial location was deemed unreliable and/or the introduction was considered too chatty. I have edited the answer to a more "academic" format. @Joseph, please feel free to take over, this is your answer after all!

Comment: @RandomSeed, I didn't consider the chattiness as a negative and couldn't find any officially posted Java Doc.  I appreciate the edit. It looks good to me. I'll keep those points in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no common class in Java that holds the MySQL error numbers. This is because each database vendor has its own error codes with their own meanings. For example, . Probably there's a constant class inside the respective jar.

As noted by @MarcB, you can create your own class with constants that represent each error based on the specific MySQL error codes from here: [Server Error Codes and Messages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html). IMO you should create the constants based on the error you want to handle in specific way, and the other errors should be handled using a generic way.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) instead of using JDBC directly. The Spring [JDBC templates](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) implement the boilerplate code for examining SQL status codes, handling connection failure, etc. It translates generic `SQLException` exceptions into appropriate specific [`DataAccessException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html) exceptions.